# CSS keyframe animation which is set on :hover won't stop on mobile touch

Tags: css, mobile, touch, css-animations, keyframe

I've got a CSS keyframe animation set up to happen on :hover of a specific icon that is used as a favorite button. It works just fine on desktop, but the animation keyframe that's set up for the :hover state won't stop on mobile device touch. How do I get it to stop for mobile or not engage in mobile?

Here's a link to the codepen:

```
http://codepen.io/mapk/pen/ZOQqaQ
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fav-btn">
    <span href="" class="favme dashicons dashicons-heart"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fav-btn {
    display:flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


@keyframes favme-anime {
  0%   { 
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: ms(0);
        -webkit-text-stroke-color: transparent;
    }
    25%  { 
        opacity:.6;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: ms(-2);
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #DC3232;
    }
    75%  { 
        opacity:.6;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: ms(3);
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #DC3232;
    }
  100% { 
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: ms(2);
        -webkit-text-stroke-color: transparent;
    }
}

@keyframes favme-hover {
    from {
        font-size: ms(3);
    }
    80% {
        font-size: ms(2);
    }
}

.favme {
    display:block;
    font-size: ms(2);
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    color: #CBCDCE;
    margin: 0;

    &.active {
        color: #DC3232;
    }
    &:hover {
        animation: favme-hover .3s infinite alternate;
    }
    &.is_animating {
        animation: favme-anime .3s;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
// Favorite Button - Heart
$('.favme').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

/* when a user clicks, toggle the 'is-animating' class */
$(".favme").on('click touchstart', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is_animating');
});

/*when the animation is over, remove the class*/
$(".favme").on('animationend', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is_animating');
});
```

Comment: Define *hovering on mobile devices*, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yout touch the button on a touch screen, it will stay in a hover state untill you touch anywhere else, therefore the animation will not end.

You can try detecting mobile devices with javascript and for example set a `no-hover` class to the button and in css put `:not('no-hover')` before `:hover`:

```
&:not('no-hover'):hover {
    animation: favme-hover .3s infinite alternate;
}
```

I don't use javascript phone detection so try asking google, there are many possibilities like http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/, https://www.abeautifulsite.net/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/ or many others.

Or use media queries to detect smaller devices and wrapp the `&:hover{some_style}`:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    &:hover {
        animation: favme-hover .3s infinite alternate;
    }
}
```